# lua string concatenation get a weird string

Tags: lua

I am coding lua scripts with three string concatenation,but the result is not what I want，the result is a weird string

```
    a = 'username=' ..usermap[counter%table.getn(usermap)]
    b = '&password=123456'
    c = a..b
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
```

the output result is:

```
username=abcd1999999
&password=123456
&password=1234569999
```

I expect c output:

```
username=abcd1999999&password=123456
```

Comment: Looks like the strings in your usermap have carriage returns (`\r') in them.

Comment: Also, Lua tables are 1-indexed, so your modulo will not give the expected result and nil on the first (remove 1 from getn, add 1 after modulo)

Comment: I got your expected result in my IDE using 5.3, 5.2 and 5.1. I substituted `usermap[counter%table.getn(usermap)]` with `username=abcd1999999` as i did not have the code for the structure.

Comment: @siffiejoe yeah you're right usermap have '\r'  end of line